# How can I set full width page layout in a default post page?

Tags: page-template, html

I want to set up my site so that when I go to any post then it should show full width page. This theme already has a full width page but I wanted it to show in the default width page. How can I accomplish this? My website link is - http://techjagot.com

The code in single.php is :-

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
          setPostViews(get_the_ID());
?>

    <?php
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    if ( get_post_meta( $postid, 'post_featpages', true ) == "Yes" ) { ?>
        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/featured-pages.php'); ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ( get_post_meta( $postid, 'post_featcontent', true ) == "Full Width Featured Content Slider"  ) { ?>
        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/featured-wide.php'); ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <div id="page" class="clearfix">

        <div id="contentleft">

            <?php if ( get_post_meta( $postid, 'post_featcontent', true ) == "Narrow Width Featured Content Slider" ) { ?>
                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/featured-narrow.php'); ?>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( get_post_meta( $postid, 'post_featgalleries', true ) == "Yes" ) { ?>
                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/featured-galleries.php'); ?>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( get_post_meta( $postid, 'post_featvideo', true ) == "Yes" ) { ?>
                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/featured-vids.php'); ?>
            <?php } ?>

            <div id="content" class="maincontent">

                <?php if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) { yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>'); } ?>

                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/banner468.php'); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="singlepost">

                <div class="post" id="post-main-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                    <div class="entry">

                        <h1 class="post-title single"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="<?php _e("বুকমার্ক", "solostream"); ?>" title="<?php _e("Permanent Link to", "solostream"); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/postinfo.php'); ?>

                        <?php if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_embed', true ) ) { ?>
                            <div class="single-video">
                                <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_embed', true ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php the_content(); ?>

                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                        <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>

                        <?php if(function_exists('the_tags')) { the_tags('<p class="tags"><strong>'. __('ট্যাগসমূহ', "solostream"). ': </strong> ', ', ', '</p>'); } ?>
                        <p class="cats"><strong><?php _e('বিভাগ', "solostream"); ?></strong>: <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>

                    </div>

                    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/auth-bio.php'); ?>

                    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/related.php'); ?>

                    <?php comments_template('', true); ?>

                </div>

                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/bot-nav.php"); ?>

            </div>
```

stylesheet.php code

/* ---------[ Full-Width Layout Styles ]--------- */

```
.fwidth #page {}

.fwidth #contentleft {
    width: 100%;
    float:none;
    }

.fwidth #content {
    width: 908px;
    }
```

If anybody demands any other code for more info then please tell me. I will provide you guys with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit your `single.php` for a full width design in your post view, is the `single.php` is responsible showing your post details.

Suppose, if your `single.php` looks like this:

```
+---------------------+
|                     |
+--------------+------+
|              |      |
|              |      |
|              |      |
|              |      |
|              |      |
+--------------+------+
+---------------------+
```

And your codes are like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="single-content">
   CONTENT
<div>

<div id="sidebar">
   <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

### ACTION

Then to achieve the full width, you have to DELETE the sidebar div completely, and have to add a 100% width to the content like:

```
.single-content{width: 100% !important;}
```

This is just a concept. I hope you can find your solution from here.

Comment: thnks bro ... but i want also wide my single php header title,author name,comment... how i can do it.. my page show now width but title,comment it's not show full width

Comment: Are you meaning a responsive design, that stretch out according to the screen/monitor? I'm asking this, because I found [your layout](http://www.projuktichowa.com/) with full width header. (as your aforementioned site is redirected)